# How to choose between fund managers?

Tags: stocks, ira, starting-out-investing

**My Situation**

A few years ago I invested with JP Morgan Chase mutual funds conservatively. Lately I was thinking about opening a more aggressive portfolio for the long term (10-15 years) and put in some money to build wealth and save for a rainy day.

A friend of mine recommended Charles Schwab intelligent portfolio. Indeed they are highly recommended by investors worldwide. Then I found out that Chase has similar app called You Invest where they monitor and rebalance your stocks at a very low fee (possibly cheaper than Schwab).

Since I am not looking to manage my investments on my own and I would need a financial advisor to do that for me, does it really make a difference who is managing my stocks? I mean they both are highly reliable firms and both are trustworthy. Schwab is probably more famous and more recommended by investors than the former, but since I am not managing them myself does it really make a difference who is managing my account?

**My Question**

I know very little about stocks or investing. What criteria should I use in cases like this to evaluate two or more fund managers when deciding where to place my investments?

Comment: This will probably get closed as offtopic for seeking product or service recommendations, but I cannot say anything bad about Schwab.

Comment: @quid Thanks for letting me know. I know how quickly this can happen here on SE, but I have nowhere else to ask. Reddit/investing has same policy :(

Comment: After doing it myself for nearly 40 years, two years ago I considered the possibility of putting some money in a similarly manage account.  I met with reps from JP Morgan, Ameritrade, Edward Jones, Merrill Lynch, etc.  
I'll spare you the details other than I came close to doing it with an aggressive JPM fund that was 125% long and 25% short.  For all of them with long term records, I didn't like the draw downs in 2008 so I did nothing with any of them.

Comment: continued: For Schwab, their management  fees were among the lowest but their fund return lagged the market by too much and I didn't feel that lagging performance warranted paying them a fee. The short answer?  Management does matter and you should compare the returns with the draw downs and find something that has the potential to  meet your goals while fitting in with your risk tolerance.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because although it involves specific brokerage products, it asked for opinions about two major brokers which I surmise that a decent number of people might be  doing  business with.  Also, the intent of the OP is sincere.

Comment: @BobBaerker thanks for sticking up for me. Closing a question is one thing, but why was I downvoted??

Comment: I don't know what's in the mind of the down voters.  The reason that I spoke on your behalf is that you are looking for help with a dilemma that many investors face, particularly those who don't have  sufficient market experience.  If sharing information and experiences assists us in having  a better chance at succeeding financially, this dead end failed that goal.  Good luck with your investing.

Comment: @Bach I have taken the liberty of editing the question to change the thrust from _which_ fund manager to choose towards _what factors should I use when choosing_. Feel free to edit/rollback if I've changed anything of import, but this might make it a better fit for the site.

Comment: If you read Daniel Kahnemann *Thinking, Fast & Slow*, you will be informed that "fund management" is mostly an illusion of validity. The lowest cost S&P 500 index funds are sufficient for the long term investor.

Comment: @mootmoot what do you mean by "illusion of validity"?

Comment: @TripeHound thanks. Looks fine to me. Now I am waiting for users to reopen this question. It would be really helpful to have such a question on site.

Comment: @Bach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_validity 
I strongly suggest getting the book, whether in printed format or audiobook

Comment: BTW, one reason that there are talk about "AI" is going to wipe out typical fund manager job, is because machine can be programmed to churn out trade decision stories as good as human.

Answer (score 4):

*Why should* you choose?

Take the easy route and invest in a set of low-cost passive funds that follow the S&P500, Russell 2000, a Total Bond Index, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make a decision, then you probably don't have enough information. You mention that you know very little about stocks or investing, and that is the problem right there. Not everyone has to try and be Ray Dalio, or Jim Simons, or Warren Buffett, but every investor should be informed enough to understand their own investments to a reasonable degree.

Here is what I would recommend for you: Start to do some research on investing and get a handle on the basics. Investopedia is a great resource. Read a lot of articles, and take all of their opinions with a big grain of salt. Then find a stock that you think might do well and buy 1 share (don't spend more than $50). Watch the stock, monitor it, research it, and you will start to get a feel for it. Do some research on dollar-cost averaging into index fund ETFs like SPY. Consider that option and then re-consider the money managers you mentioned in light of the new knowledge you have. At that point you will be better equipped to make a decision.

Being a passive investor is great, but whatever your investment style, being educated about the investments you are making is essential, not a nice-to-have.

Source: I have been investing for over 9 years, I am the President of the Investment Club at Hobart and William Smith Colleges, and run an investment partnership called Gansett Group.

You can find us at https://gansettgroup.com
and https://www.linkedin.com/company/hwsinvestmentclub

Best of luck, and happy investing!

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to do the research beforehand. From my experience, the most important part is managing fees (both management and associated fees).

I've used 2 financial advisors and 5 robo-advisors in the past and the S&P 500 beat all of them. The management fees ranged from 0.25% to 1% and the performance certainly didn't justify the fee. These portfolios lagged behind the market during uptrends and didn't protect much downside during downtrends.

I will never use a financial advisor again but I still use robo advisors. Robo advisors have lower fees and you have more control if you want to rebalance or liquidate.

Ultimately, you'll do better if you just buy individual ETFs and stocks, but robo advisors make the process a little bit easier. Wealthfront and Betterment have been my preferred services so far.